# Code::Blocks with MinGW linking fail

Tags: c++, c, linker, mingw, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks (ver. 13.12) with MinGW (ver. 4.7.1) on 32-bit Windows 7.

While trying to build my project I get the following error after the compilation step:

```
Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o cb_dlv.exe
...huge list of *.o files...
in 'D:\Workspace\cb_dlv' failed.
```

There's certainly no problem with toolchain executables as my other projects compile and link pretty well and all the tools are in their right places. `mingw32-g++.exe` is seen from `cmd` so no problems with `PATH` variable. Cleaning workspace also doesn't seem to help in any way. I've already tried to move project files so that the path has no spaces in it, but it didn't help either. As well as reopening/reinstalling/rebooting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, but i think that's happen when you doesn't install CB at the standard location. Somewhere in the menu you can find an option, that will search for the mingw location, and i think after that it should work.
I used CB last time long time ago, so sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: CB is installed into default directory and MinGW location is set and seen from CB. As I've mentioned above there're no problems with tolchain executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've found the solution, here it is.

The main problem was that on Windows 7, the limit for the length of a command line is around 32K characters. MinGW compiler and linker hit that limit while building projects with huge amount of files in them. This is a fundamental limitation of Windows APIs that MinGW uses.

The solution: shorten the command line in any way you like: merge some files in one, separate project into several ones, rename subdirectories with long names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your project to use a custom makefile? What are your build system variables? 
Are the object files available in D:\Workspace\cb_dlv?
Is that the only output of your compile log or is there other output before it?
are your project's build targets set up sensibly?

you should see the build system log that it is compiling your c/c++ files to object files before the last linking stage happens i.e. stuff like:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -c D:\Workspace\cb_dlv\file.c -o D:\Workspace\cb_dlv\obj\Debug\file.o
```

Please flesh out this question some more and I might be able to help you.

Comment: No, I haven't used custom makefiles, just the usual Build/Rebuild Code::Blocks options.

Comment: Object files are produced and available. I'm compiling with the following options (fragment of compile log): `mingw32-g++.exe -w -nostdinc -nostdinc++ ...some internal defines... ...list of headers' directories... -ID: -c "D:\Workspace\dlv\Stack.cpp" -o "obj\Stack.o"`. The reason of using -nostdinc and -nostdinc++ is that I'm trying to compile a library which has its own implementation of standard headers.